# How to use string_agg/group_concat in salesforce marketing cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, sql, automationstudio, sqlserver

I am trying to write something similar in query studio on SFMC. But keep getting string_agg is not recognized as a built-in function name. Please help. Also, what could be the alternative.
Thanks

SELECT STRING_AGG(Genre, ',') AS Result
FROM Genres;

Same result when using group_concat

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**EDIT - 8/9/2023**

As mentioned by @charliefay in his comment, STRINGG_AGG() is now accepted inside SFMC

---

Neither of these functions are available inside of SFMC Query Activities.

SQL in SFMC is based on SQL Server 2016, but even that is not a full representation (as shown in the official docs **[here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.mc_as_sql_reference.htm&type=5)**)  `STRING_AGG()` was introduced in SQL Server 2017, so is not a capability inside of SFMC.

> SQL support for the SQL Query Activity is based on, but doesn’t precisely correspond to, SQL Server 2016 capabilities.

And `GROUP_CONCAT` is not available in T-SQL (SQL Server) and is actually part of MySQL. This means it is also not available inside of SFMC SQL.

**[Here](https://gortonington.com/sfmc-sql-data-into-a-delimited-string/)** is an alternative solution for creating a delimited string from my blog that may help using `STUFF()` and `FOR XML PATH()`.

```sql
SELECT a.id,
emailStr = STUFF(
  (
    SELECT ',' + b.email
    FROM [myDE] b
    WHERE a.id = b.id
    FOR XML PATH('')
  ), 1, 1, '')
FROM [myDE]
GROUP BY ID
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I explored all possible options for group concat. Finally found expected code here.

Comment: STRING_AGG() is now supported by SFMC. `STRING_AGG(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(max),Id), ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY Id DESC)`